# Evenly dividing a discrete space

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Suppose I have a 2D discrete space with coordinates 0 to 19 in the horizontal direction and 0 to 19 in the vertical direction.  Coordinates could then range from [0, 0] to [19, 19].

I can evenly divide this space into four parts and specify the coordinates that each part can hold.

- Q1 (top left): [0, 0] to [9, 9]
- Q2 (top right): [0, 10] to [9, 19]
- Q3 (bottom left): [10, 0] to [19, 9]
- Q4 (bottom right): [10, 10] to [19, 19]

Now, maybe I'm having a brain fart, but how is this generalized?

Specifically, I need to divide into four equal parts a space that is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] to [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255], but I'm also interested in seeing how it's done for arbitrary sizes and dimensions.

Thanks!

Comment: $$9 = \frac{19-1}{2}$$
$$10 = \frac{19+1}{2}$$

Comment: @Théophile : Thanks!  So it looks like I apply this pattern to only the first two coordinates of the 8D space to determine which "quadrant" a vector falls in, and the rest of the coordinates (3 - 8) have the full range of values.

Comment: Yes, that would be one to do it. I didn't see at first that you're in 8 dimensions. You could, for example, choose any two dimensions to be subdivided that way, and the remainder would take on the full range. It really depends on what your purpose is.